# Template Child Class Overriding a Parent Class's Virtual Function

Tags: c++, templates, virtual

The below code compiles with gcc v4.3.3 and the templated child class seems to be overriding a virtual function in the parent, but doesn't that break the rule that you cannot have a virtual template function?  Or is something else happening that I don't understand?

```
class BaseClass
{
public:
  virtual void Func(int var)
  {
    std::cout<<"Base int "<<var<<std::endl;
  }

  virtual void Func(double var)
  {
    std::cout<<"Base double "<<var<<std::endl;
  }
};

template <class TT>
class TemplateClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
  using BaseClass::Func;
  virtual void Func(TT var)
  {
    std::cout<<"Child TT "<<var<<std::endl;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  BaseClass a;
  TemplateClass<int> b;
  BaseClass *c = new TemplateClass<int>;

  int intVar = 3;
  double doubleVar = 5.5;

  a.Func(intVar);
  a.Func(doubleVar);
  b.Func(intVar);
  b.Func(doubleVar);
  c->Func(intVar);
  c->Func(doubleVar);
  delete c;
}
```

This then outputs:

Base int 3
Base double 5.5
Child TT 3
Base double 5.5
Child TT 3
Base double 5.5

as I hoped, but I'm not sure why it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A class template may have virtual member functions.

A member function template cannot be virtual.  That is, the following is invalid:

```
class C
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    virtual void f();
};
```

In addition, if a derived class has a member function template with the same name as a virtual function in a base class, it does not override the virtual function.  So, if `TemplateClass::Func` had been a member function template, e.g.,

```
template <typename T>
void Func(T var) { /* ... */ }
```

it would not have overridden `BaseClass::Func`.

Comment: I see my confusion with template classes vs template functions now.  So in the above code TemplateClass<int> is making a virtual Func(int) on compile, which then overrides the parent class's virtual Func(int)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't break the rule. The actual rule is 14.5.2/4:

> A member function template shall not be virtual. [Example:
>
> ```
> template <class T> struct AA {
>   template <class C> virtual void g(C); // error
>   virtual void f(); // OK
> };
> ```